# The way to realise data access

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

There are a several articles about true data access in MVC. I tried to make the best one according to the architecture flexibility. My way is following:

1. ADO .NET Entity Data Model (*.edmx from Entity Framework) with default code generation.
2. Common repository interface

   ```
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        T Get(int id);
        void Create(T entityToCreate);
        void Edit(T entityToEdit);
        void Delete(T entityToDelete);
    }
   ```
3. Interface (with particular methods of the current class), class with real implementation of methods. For example

   ```
   public interface ITestingRepository: IGenericRepository<Testing>
   {
       List<dynamic> GetTestingUser(int id);
       List<dynamic> GetNotTestingUser(int idTesting, Guid idCompany);
       List<Testing> List(Guid CompanyId);
   }

   public class TestingRepository : ITestingRepository
   {
      private TestEverybody _entities = new TestEverybody();

      public List<Testing> List(Guid CompanyId)
      {
          return _entities.Testing.Where(t => t.idCompany == CompanyId).ToList();
      }
      public void Edit(Testing productToEdit)
      {
          var originalProduct = Get(productToEdit.id);
          _entities.ApplyCurrentValues(originalProduct.EntityKey.EntitySetName, productToEdit);
          _entities.SaveChanges();
      }
      public void Create(Testing productToCreate)
      {
          _entities.Testing.AddObject(productToCreate);
          _entities.SaveChanges();
      }
      //other methods
   }
   ```
4. The following data access method in the controller

   ```
    public class TestingController : Controller
    {
      //
      // GET: /Testing/
      private ITestingRepository _repository;
      public TestingController() : this(new TestingRepository()) { }

      public TestingController(ITestingRepository repository)
      {
         _repository = repository;
      }
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Create(Testing newobject)
      {
          _repository.Create(newobject);            
          return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Edit(Testing item)
      {
         _repository.Edit(item);
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
    }
   ```

Is it a good one? Have I any mistakes there?

Answer (score 8):

Your code seems really good, I would change the `ITestingRepository` methods to return `IEnumerable<>` instead of `List<>`.

Also, I suggest you would add a method signature to your generic repository interface that would let you query your DbContext.

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
{
    T Get(int id);
    void Create(T entityToCreate);
    void Edit(T entityToEdit);
    void Delete(T entityToDelete);
    IEnumerable<T> Get(Expression<Func<T,bool>> whereClause)
}
```

Then you can use it this way

```
//Class example, I don't know what Testing class is
public class Testing
{
    public string PropertyOne { get; set;}
    public string PropertyTwo { get; set;}
}

public class TestingRepository
{
    //Method implementation
    public IEnumerable<Testing> Get(Expression<Func<Testing,bool>> whereClause)
    {
        IQueryable<Testing> result = _entities.Testing;

        if(whereClause != null)
            return result.Where(whereClause);

        return result.ToList();
    }
}

public static void AMethod() //Just to show an example at work!
{
    List<Testing> testings = new TestingRepository().Get(x => x.PropertyOne == "Hello" && x.PropertyTwo == "World").ToList();
}
```

Finally, you might want to implement a generic repository class that implements your interface (a `public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T>`, I won't write it down for you but you could check this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640294/Learning-MVC-Part-Generic-Repository-Pattern-in